# Tapestry 5 - run javascript function on client-side field validation success/failure

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, tapestry

In Tapestry 5, in a form, I need to log (via google analytics) when each individual form field has been completed and passed the client-side validation successfully.

I need to do this for each individual field in real-time, even if the form is not submitted, so waiting until form submission and doing this on the server is not an option.

Is there a way (out of the box) to hook into the success/failure of the javascript client-side validation provided by Tapestry 5?

The two possibilities I can think of would be:

1. A Tapestry api to provide a callback function to the success/failure events.
2. Listening for some Tapestry custom event on success/failure.

But I cannot find anything in the documentation about either of these existing. Is either of these options possible, or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague suggested overriding the `Tapestry.FieldEventManager.validateInput` function using ProptypeJS Class.create.

```
Tapestry.FieldEventManager = Class.create(Tapestry.FieldEventManager, {
                                 validateInput : function($super) {
                                     var isValidationFailure = $super();

                                     // can use this.field inside this function to access the field being validated

                                     if(!isValidationFailure) {
                                         // LOGIC ON VALIDATION SUCCESS
                                     } else {
                                         // LOGIC ON VALIDATION FAILURE
                                     }
                                     return isValidationFailure;
                                 }
                             });
```

This solves the problem nicely, allowing for clean readable code and easy access to both the super implementation and the actual field itself, which I needed to do my tracking logic. And the best part is it just works, with validateInput being called on each individual form field when it loses focus. No detailed knowledge of, or messy code around, the events that drive the validation engine required!

FYI validateInput will also run for each form field on form submission - that can be worked around by overriding Tapestry.FormEventManager.handleSubmit to hook into form submission logic... but that is a little beyond the scope of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to attach clientside event listeners to achieve what you want. Take a look at `Tapestry.FormEventManager.handleSubmit` in tapestry.js. Form submission fires the following clientside events:

```
/**
 * Event that allows observers to perform cross-form validation after
 * individual fields have performed their validation. The form element is
 * passed as the event memo. Observers may set the validationError property
 * of the Form's Tapestry object to true (which will prevent form
 * submission).
 */
FORM_VALIDATE_EVENT: "tapestry:formvalidate",

/**
 * Event fired just before the form submits, to allow observers to make
 * final preparations for the submission, such as updating hidden form
 * fields. The form element is passed as the event memo.
 */
FORM_PREPARE_FOR_SUBMIT_EVENT: "tapestry:formprepareforsubmit",

/**
 * Form event fired after prepare.
 */
FORM_PROCESS_SUBMIT_EVENT: "tapestry:formprocesssubmit",

/**
 * Event, fired on a field element, to cause observers to validate the
 * input. Passes a memo object with two keys: "value" (the raw input value)
 * and "translated" (the parsed value, usually meaning a number parsed from
 * a string). Observers may invoke Element.showValidationMessage() to
 * identify that the field is in error (and decorate the field and show a
 * popup error message).
 */
FIELD_VALIDATE_EVENT: "tapestry:fieldvalidate",

/**
 * Event notification, on a form object, that is used to trigger validation
 * on all fields within the form (observed by each field's
 * Tapestry.FieldEventManager).
 */
FORM_VALIDATE_FIELDS_EVENT: "tapestry:validatefields",
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could indeed hook into the events, but I found a solution which is more high level and avoids having to do that (see my answer), which worked better in this case.