# Listening on Apache Tapestry form events

Tags: javascript, jquery, tapestry

I'm a Back-end dev, and recently inherited a couple of legacy Apache Tapestry systems. My skills with Tapestry are null my knowledge on javascript medium.

I want to disable a submit button right before the submit is made to avoid multiple submits.
A very simple

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form").submit(function () {
        $("#submitbutton").attr("disabled", true);
        return true;
    });
});
```

approach wont do because the submit event is propagated before Tapestry does the client-side validation, so I could be disabling the button on a submint attempt that will fail validation.

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599346/tapestry-5-run-javascript-function-on-client-side-field-validation-success-fai) question I learned that Tapestry also propagetes its own events, and if I could listen on `tapestry:formprocesssubmit` That would probably solve my problem.

I have my `CreateContract.tml` file with the form, fields and buttons that already work, I have my `CreateContract.java` file with

```
@Import(library = {
            "context:js/jquery.mask.min.js",
            "context:js/maintain-contracts.js",
            "context:js/zone-overlay.js"},
            stylesheet = "context:layout/zone-overlay.css")
```

And my `maintain-contracts.js` file with

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form").on('tapestry:formprepareforsubmit', function () {
        console.log("I want to arrive here!");
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work.
On [this](https://users.tapestry.apache.narkive.com/eJsFRDqz/confirm-mixin-with-form-validation-errors) mailing list thread I see people discussing very similar matters, but they go about listening on events on a different fashion, that I don't quite grasp.

Should I create the listener inside the initializer?

I'm reffering to the event as `'tapestry:formprepareforsubmit'` instead of `Tapestry.FORM_PREPARE_FOR_SUBMIT_EVENT` because on both my `maintain-contracts.js` and my console the Tapestry variable is empty - why is that?

What about the `.on` versus `.bind` versus `.observe` trichotomy?

the [first links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599346/tapestry-5-run-javascript-function-on-client-side-field-validation-success-fai)'s question was solved using `ProptypeJS` Class.create, but I think i dont have access to that.

I'm I going about that wrong?

Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading Tapestry's source code, i found out that the event is not called `tapestry:formprepareforsubmit`, but `t5:form:prepare-for-submit`, even though I found no documentation of that anywhere.

So

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form").on('t5:form:prepare-for-submit', function () {
        console.log("I want to arrive here!");
    });
});
```

Works perfectly.

Comment: You can find some documentation about it here:
https://tapestry.apache.org/current/coffeescript/events.html
But yes it is hard to find if you don't know it exists

Answer (score 0):

*Not an analysis of why your approach doesn't work, but a useful referral nonetheless:*

Geoff Callender, creator of [Tapestry JumpStart](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/home.html), has an excellent description of how duplicate form submissions can be avoided using a mixin.

See http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/javascript/creatingmixins1